# After Releasing Application What to do If you want to Change the XcDatamodel?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

I am developing an application for iPhone.

Sometimes I change the xcdatamodel file.

Of course things will go wrong. But no problem. I just delete the application from the IPhone simulator and start a new again. I am developing after all.

Well, say I have 1 million subscribers with settings bookmark, etc.

Say I want to change the managed object model. Say I am updating my application. I can't just delete the old application and use a new one.

What should I do then at that time?

Is managed object model unchangeable after release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this using a [Core Data Migration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399)